# array like object using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to JavaScript and am currently reading about arrays. I saw the following code on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections) about how how some objects do not share the array methods and a workaround:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Specifically the `prototype.forEach.call(arguments` have not seen that before. From the `.call` documentation the first argument is the `this` object yet an `arguments` object is provided here. Can anyone walk me along what is happening here?

Comment: As long as there is a length there is a way.